# f.write only writes unchanged variables?

Tags: python, variables, pycharm, fwrite

Here is my summarized code:

```
Var1 = 10
Var2 = 100
Var3 = 300
Var4 = 0

Amount = input("Blahblahblah amount for Var 4: ")
Amount2 = input("Blahblahblah amount for Var 1: ")

Amount2 + Amount * Var3 == Var4
Var4 - Var2 == Amount2
 if Amount2 == 20:
     Amount - Var4
 else:
     Amount + Var4 == Var 2

Y = input("Type 'Y' to continue:")
if (Y == "Y"):
    try:
       with open("Test.txt", "a") as f:
           f.write(f"Var 2 == {Var2}, Var 4 == {Var4} \n")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

The problem is that in Test.txt it writes `Var 2 == 100, Var 4 == 0` insted of the real answer.
So whatever I write in the 'Amount' or 'Amount 2' it will always = to `Var 2 == 100, Var 4 == 0`.
Is this a dumb mistake I can't see?

Comment: What do you expect `Amount2 + Amount * Var3 == Var4` to do?

Comment: You are incorrectly or simply not assigning values to your variables throughout your code. You should assign a value on the right side of an equal sign to a variable on the left. E.g. `Var4=Amount2+Amount*Var3` to change the value of Var4. You also use ==, which is not the assignment operator but instead checks for equality.

Comment: `==` *tests* if two values are equal; it does not *assert* that two expressions are the same from that point on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those lines you are not reassigning values to your variables.

```py
Amount2 + Amount * Var3 == Var4
Var4 - Var2 == Amount2
if Amount2 == 20: 
   Amount - Var4
else:
   Amount + Var4 == Var 2
```

To reassign a value to a variables use:

```py
# definition
a = 1
b = 10
# reassignment
a = a + b
# the new value of a will be 11
# a = 1 + 10
```

Moreover, avoid calling variables with capital letters (this should be used only when defining classes).

Comment: It gives me another error. ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str```

Comment: When you receive an input from `input` built-in function, it is a string. You have to cast it to your desired type. `a = int(a)` converts a string into integer.